# Cucumber step repeat NullPointerException

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, rest-assured

I am trying to run the feature a and feature b which has same steps like 
    below

```
feature a:

Scenario Outline: Verify correct entity values
  When  Performing the get request to localhost:"<port>"/"<endpoint>"
   Then The response status should be 200 and json body containing "Apps is running"

feature b: 

Scenario Outline: Verify incorrect entity values
    When Performing the post request with correct file to localhost:"<port>"/"<endpoint>""<superregion>""<entity>""<filename>""<contenttype>"
    Then The response status should be 400 and response message is "<entity> is not a valid entity type."
    Examples:
      | port | endpoint     | superregion | entity | filename | contenttype |
      | 8081 | api/v1/admin | ANBS        | V      | anbs.tsv | anbsFile    |
```

When I tried to use same steps I have got an error message:

```
# CheckTest.checkJsonBodyContains(int,String)
  java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.apitesting.steps.checkJsonBodyContains(CheckTest.java:27)
    at ✽.The response status should be 201 and json body containing "success"(src/test/resources/features/GSOUpload.feature:6)
```

This is the body of `checkJsonBodyContains`:

```
    @Then("^The response status should be (\\d{3}) and json body containing \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void checkJsonBodyContains(int statusCode, String message){
        assertEquals(statusCode, response.getStatusCode());
        assertThat(response.getBody().asString(), containsString(message));
    }**
```

please help me out how to sort out the null pointer exception the above steps I am reusing many tests.

Comment: Check the response variable. Is it getting initialized properly and does it have the correct value?

Comment: Please find the response. HTTP/1.1 201 Created
 GSOUploadTest.postRequestWithCorrectGSOFile(int,String,String,String,String,String)
    Then The response status should be 201 and json body containing "success"                                         # HealthCheckTest.checkJsonBodyContains(int,String)
      java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.hotels.sem.katamari.apitesting.steps.HealthCheckTest.checkJsonBodyContains(HealthCheckTest.java:27)
 at ✽.The response status should be 201 and json body containing "success"(src/test/resources/features/GSOUpload.feature:6

Comment: Request method: POST
Request URI: http://localhost:8081/api/v1/admin?sr=APAC&entity=D
Query params: sr=APAC
entity=D
Form params: <none>
Path params: <none>
Headers:  Accept=*/*
Content-Type=multipart/form-data
Cookies:  <none>
Multiparts:  ------------    Content-Disposition: form-data; name = gsoFile; filename = apac.tsv
Content-Type: text/tab-separated-values
[B@3a393455
Body:   <none>
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: akka-http/10.0.9
Date: Fri, 20 Apr 2018 17:19:42 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 28
{
    "success": true,
    "errors": [       
    ]
}

Comment: Add AssertNotNull("Need a response", response);